# How to get access to funds on keys that were derived using public key child derivation? BIP 32

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, public-key

If I have a key m/0'/0' and I'm using CKDpub to derive m/0'/0'/0 and then CKDPub to get m/0'/0'/0/0. How do I get access to the funds on the addresses generated by CKDPub?

Can m/0'/0' ->  CKDPriv -> CKDPriv => m/0'/0'/0/0 key use those funds?

Another way: if I take a private/public key pair, use CKDPub on the public and CKDPriv on the private, do they yield the same public keys?

Answer (score 2):

> if I take a private/public key pair, use CKDPub on the public and CKDPriv on the private, do they yield the same public keys?

For unhardened childs, [yes](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#private-parent-key--public-child-key).